# Android sqlite delete row failure

Tags: android, sqlite, delete-row

I'm trying to delete a row in a table where I know the row exists. I tried:

```
final String s = "DELETE from %s where Name = '%s'";        
String sql = String.format(s, GetTableName(), sListName);
Cursor cr= GetUserDb().GetSQLiteDb().rawQuery(sql, null);
```

and I tried:

```
String sWhere = String.format("Name = '%s'", sListName);
long lRowsUpdated = GetUserDb().GetSQLiteDb().delete(GetTableName(), sWhere, null);


** sWhere >> Name = 'groceries' **
** sql >> DELETE from Lists where Name = 'groceries' **
```

There is no crash or logcat exception but the row is still not deleted. Is there something I'm  missing? Maybe I have a lock on it somewhere else or I need to set certain permissions in my Manifest or something?

Comment: ALSO my primary key is the sListName which is TEXT not sure if that matters or not...

Comment: umm... are you sure about the String.format()? Is it return the correct statement? Try String sql = String.format(s, new Object[]{GetTableName(), sListName});

Comment: @mihail - thanks.  I tried your suggestion in which sql = DELETE from Lists where Name = 'groceries'  and STILL it doesn't remove the row and thee are no errors thrown . I think the issue is just something else entirely....

Comment: try executing GetUserDb().GetSQLiteDb().execSQL(sql); but it is void function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delete() from SqliteDatabase - this returns the count of affected rows. E.g. delete(tablename, "name=?", new String[] { aString } )

Comment: Thanks I did try that as you can see in my original post and no luck.

Comment: Please show create statement and an example about the values. There's nothing wrong with the code - it must be the values.

Comment: a.) You use mixed case for tablenames (Lists), columns (Name) and your listvalue is lower case (groceries)? Is it really lowercase? b.) Is there an open cursor when you try to delete this row? c.) Is there some sort of referential integrity in your database (PK=grocerie is FK in another table)?

Comment: I suspect Harald may be on to something here. I haven't had chance to test that out yet...thx for the tip Harald!

Comment: Harald nailed it. The primary key was 'Groceries' and my query used 'groceries'. Darn case sensitivity!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
       SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("DELETE FROM " + getTableName() + "WHERE Name=?");
       stmt.bindString(1, sListName);
   stmt.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, however, how do you know if stmt.execute() succeeds?

Comment: For some reason Android doesn't have the method that returns the number of rows deleted (executeUpdateDelete()) in API versions lower than 11... But personally I'm deleting rows which I know are there. If it doesn't succeed, it means the row didn't exist - which means I get the desired result anyway...

Comment: And don't forget to call stmt.close() at the end

Comment: Didn't work . Same results, I'm thinking its not how I'm calling my sql delete but maybe how my table is structured....does primary key have to be _ID? My primary key is TEXT (sListName)

Comment: AFAIK, your primary key has to be _id if you're using cursor adapters. Don't know if it's a requirement for other purposes, although my primary key is always _id due to this fact.

Answer (score 0):

if the column you're trying to have your key by is sListName you should have delete where sListName = '%s' unless you have another column that is called Name that you are trying to delete, but if that isn't your primary key you might end up getting two rows in your delete.

You can always use the emulator and an adb shell and just go run the sqlite3 shell command and try your SQL statements. If you type yours in and get 0 rows affected, you know you're statement is messed up, not your java.

If you're not using any built in CurorAdapters or ContentProviders your primary key does not need to be named _ID, it can be named whatever. As for the type, in SQLite3, it's really just a suggestion on how to cast it, you can put whatever data in whatever column you want.

Comment: Thanks. My statement returns 0 rows which means it didn't delete anything. I do use :  delete where sListName = 'Test' so I know my SQL statement is correct. I know the row is there because I run a query before this to verify that....I just can't figure what could be the issue. Could it be thet last query I ran is somehow causing issues?

Comment: What is your table schema? I'm not convinced that it's not an issue of column name/variable name/query name used mix up that is causing the problem.